# Whence Whitehead's essence?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, set-theory, logic

In the article *Quine’s New Foundations* of The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy (Summer 2019 Edition), Thomas Forster writes:

> In [1944] Hailperin gave the first of a number of finite axiomatisations of NF now known. Many of them exploit the function $x\mapsto \{y|x\in y\}$
> which is injective and total and is an $\in$-isomorphism. This function was known to Whitehead, who suggested to Quine that $\{y|x\in y\}$
> should be called the “essence” of $x$ (a terminology clearly suggested by a view of sets as properties-in-extension).

How did Alfred North Whitehead communicate the essential point of view to Quine?

Comment: In what sense "communicate to"?  [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willard_Van_Orman_Quine#Education)'s thesis supervisor was Alfred North Whitehead.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the supervisor information. It would be nice to have a quotable reference, if that is available.

Comment: Possible sources to be checked: Quine's *Set Theory and its Logic* (1969) and *Whitehead and the rise of modern logic* (1941=.

Comment: Having said that, the analogy is quite reasonable, equating the *essence* with the collection of all properties.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! I got hold of the texts. :) Yes, the term is quite appropriate.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I did not find anything about it in either of those texts, unfortunately.